# How to write a macro that iterates an array of strings and displays one of them at any given time in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice, array, string

I teach Spelling at an elementary school. To make class more entertaining, I decided to add interactive content.

[In this example,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE8i2.jpg) students are given a presentation. The picture in the slide is an apple. The consonants are already given. It's the kids' job to find the right vowels.

Above and under each box containing a vowel is one button. When pressed on, the character displayed should change to the next or previous content of an array. If the first or last element is reached it wraps around. In this example the array is `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]`. Clicking `+` should therefore loop in this order: `a - e - i - o - u - a - e - ...` In contrast clicking `-` should loop in the following order: `a - u - o - i - e - a - u - ...`

[In this second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GW3B.jpg) the array is `["ch", "gh", "ph", "sh", "th"]`.

How do I write the code for this function?

p.s. Microsoft PowerPoint macro is also okay but securing the software might not be easy... We are severely underfunded :(

Comment: You've tagged this with microsoft-powerpoint and mention that a PowerPoint macro is ok, but your title says you're working in Impress. They're not the same. Please remove the stuff that doesn't apply, and then include any code you've tried so far. People will generally help you fix code that's broken but this isn't a code-writing service.